# MongoDB сортировка вложенных элементов

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Имею древовидную структуру вложенных массивов:

```
    {
    "message": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "647ecc723c323c76a8ec8b50",
            "children": [
                {
                    "_id": "647ecc883c323c76a8ec8b53",
                    "indicators": [],
                    "mainCategorie": false,
                    "title": "Подпроцесс 1 Бизнес процесса 1",
                    "__v": 0,
                    "children": [],
                    "operations": [
                        {
                            "_id": "647ed7434e77ac4df6b962bf",
                            "children": [],
                            "operations": [],
                            "indicators": [],
                            "mainCategorie": false,
                            "title": "Операция 4 к Подпроцесс №1.",
                            "index": 2,
                            "__v": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "647ed73f4e77ac4df6b962bc",
                            "children": [],
                            "operations": [],
                            "indicators": [],
                            "mainCategorie": false,
                            "title": "Операция 3 к Подпроцесс №1",
                            "index": 0,
                            "__v": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "647ed7374e77ac4df6b962b6",
                            "children": [],
                            "operations": [],
                            "indicators": [],
                            "mainCategorie": false,
                            "title": "Операция 1 к Подпроцесс №1",
                            "index": 3,
                            "__v": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "647ed73b4e77ac4df6b962b9",
                            "children": [],
                            "operations": [],
                            "indicators": [],
                            "mainCategorie": false,
                            "title": "Операция 2 к Подпроцесс №1",
                            "index": 1,
                            "__v": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "operations": [],
            "indicators": [],
            "mainCategorie": true,
            "title": "Бизнес процесс 1",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "647ee6b2a585b43415d8d4ea",
            "children": [],
            "operations": [],
            "indicators": [],
            "mainCategorie": true,
            "title": "Бизнес процесс 2",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Необходимо у массивов operations сортировать значения по ключу "index".

Запрос у меня сейчас выглядит следующим образом:

```
    export const getBusinessProcesses = async (req, res) => {
  try {

    let data = await BpTree.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          mainCategorie: true,
        },
      },

      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "b-processes",
          localField: "children",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "children",
          pipeline: [
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "b-processes",
                localField: "children",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "children",
              },
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "b-processes",
                localField: "operations",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "operations",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },

      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "b-processes",
          localField: "operations",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "operations",
          pipeline: [
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "b-processes",
                localField: "operations",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "operations",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ]);

    return res.status(200).json({
      message: "Success",
      data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ err: err.message });
  }
};
```

Простым добавлением { $sort: { index: 1 } } или $sortArray не обойтись.
Если просто сделать запрос

```
let data = await BpTree.aggregate([{ $sort: { index: 1 } }]);
```

то массив сортируется, но само собой без древовидной структуры.
Как я понимаю все дело во вложенности, но как правильно добавить в мою структуру, не могу понять.
Буду признателен за любую помощь.

Comment: Возможно ответ ты найдешь тут... https://stackru.com/questions/43231943/mongodb-sortirovat-vlozhennyij-massiv-obektov Но у меня встречный вопрос - зачем пихать в один документ коллекции столько вложенной информации?

Comment: Пробовал похожую логику  - не получилось. Я понимаю, что мне нужно как-то разобрать часть данных, отсортировать и сгруппировать обратно.  Пихаю все в один документ, потому что на фронте будет древовидная структура, как раз примерно как в доке у монги) с не определенным количеством вложенности документов у каждого ребенка должны быть операции у каждой операции должны быть показатели. Пока додумался только до такого.

Comment: Нужно различать "хранение" и "отправку" данных... Хранить можно как угодно, как и как угодно формировать данные для отправки. Тут же все в кучу свалено, отсюда и проблемы...